# Why do the residuals have to be uncorrelated with the predictor variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, residuals

In linear regression, the residuals have to be uncorrelated with the predictor variable. Is it true, and if it, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with residuals? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Umberto: A residual is the difference between the modeled value and the actual value, e.g., in regression we have y^=b^+m^x , then, the residual at a data point (x_i,y_i) is y_i -b^+m^x_i

Answer (score 2):

The **true error term** has to be uncorrelated with the regressors, in order for the estimator to have certain desirable properties.

The residuals in OLS estimation are *by design* orthogonal to the regressors, $\mathbf X'\mathbf {\hat u} = 0$, and since, also by design, they have zero mean, they are also, by design, uncorrelated with the regressors.

Comment: +1 I think the OP has somehow misinterpreted the residual plot.

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding this. I understand that each row of $X$ is orthogonal to $\hat{u}$. But I don't quite see what this has to do with correlation or covariance. Could you please expand on this?

Comment: @user5965026 Orthogonality is $E(X'e) = 0$. Covariance is  $E(X'e) - E(X') E(e)$. When $E(e)=0$, orthogonality is equivalent to covariance.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Ah I see. In this case, why did you put expectation around $E[X'e]$? $X'e$ is constant right?

Comment: @user5965026 I am not sure I understand. Why do you think it is a constant?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Are you using $e$ here to represent the unobserved error or residuals? If it's the residual, then doesn't least squares always give $X'e = 0$, the zero vector, which is constant?

Comment: @user5965026 $e$ was used to represent any variable. The OLS residuals reflect in the sample, the assumption that the true error and the regressors are orthogonal in the population. The residuals are random variables too, by the way. That their product with the regressors equal zero, is the answer to the question "are the residuals orthogonal/uncorrelated with the regressors?" The question that includes stochastic concepts, precedes the answer.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos : Is it fair to say that pairwise uncorrelated errors show lack of general bias or "systemic" error? I mean, non-zero correlation could be seen as reflecting an underlying "systemic" pattern, and same for the lack of correlation between a regressor and its residuals?

Comment: @MSIS We are talking here about "linear dependence", meaning that we can have a systemic pattern as you say only of the non-linear form. The standard case in econometrics is the presence of conditional heteroskedasticity, that can exist together with zero linear dependence. This too is "systemic pattern" -and very realistic to expect to exist, by the way.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Thank you, very clear. One more, if I may: Is the condition of the expected value of the errors being 0 also related to y^ being an unbiased estimator of the true y values? Or is the condition just needed/used to apply Gauss-Markov?

Comment: @MSIS This is just an assumption for convenience. If $Ε(u)\neq 0$, then this non-zero mean is absorbed by the constant term of the linear regression during estimation phase, and  no real harm is done.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Thanks again, Alecos.